# I want to display some database query entries in my base.html

Tags: django

I have a multi website page with a base.html which contains similar information across pages, like logo, company name etc.

I created two models

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_profile')
    company_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_address3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_phone1 = PhoneField()
    company_phone2 = PhoneField()
    company_email = models.EmailField()
    company_linkedin = models.URLField()
    company_facebook = models.URLField()
    company_twitter = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name


class CompanyServices(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    service_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_services')
    service_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service_name
```

and two views

```
def base_view(request):
    company_profile = get_object_or_404(CompanyProfile)

    context = {
        'profile': company_profile,
    }
    return render(request, 'webpages/base.html', context=context)


def index_view(request):
    company_services = CompanyServices.objects.all()

    context = {
        'services': company_services,
    }

    return render(request, 'webpages/index.html', context=context)
```

in my URL.py, I am not loading base at all, since it was extended in my index.html.

```
app_name = 'webpages'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index_view, name='home')
]
```

when I try to load the index with template tags from base.html, like so

```
<div class="container d-flex">
      <div class="contact-info mr-auto">
        <i class="icofont-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:contact@example.com">***{{profile.company_email}}***</a>
        <i class="icofont-phone"></i> ***{{profile.company_name}}***
      </div>
```

It doesnt load from the database. how can I do this or it's imposible?

is the base.html supposed to contain only static information?

Comment: Which CompanyProfile do you expecting to appear on this page?

Comment: Try printing the profile information in console. ie add `print(company_profile.company_email)` before you return the view and have a look to see if it is actually getting the information or not.

Comment: @IvanStarostin. I wanted to print this {{profile.company_name}}

Comment: company_name of **which** CompanyProfile? CompanyProfile is a model (db table) containing 0-M records -  **which one** of them are you expecting to see on this page?

Comment: @GTBebbo, I did this:
def base_view(request):
    company_profile = get_object_or_404(CompanyProfile)
    print(company_profile.company_email)
    context = {
        'profile': company_profile,
    }

    return render(request, 'webpages/base.html', context=context)
but nothing on the console

Comment: try just printing `company_profile`. Your __str__ function should just output the name or you should get a <CompanyProfile> Model object

Comment: @GTBebbo the company profile does not load, I tried the same thing on the index view, but it loaded the queryset for the Companyservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate base view for the base template. It's not getting called, which is why you're not seeing it print in the console when you hit the `index_view`.

You'd need to do something like:

```
def index_view(request):
    company_profile = get_object_or_404(CompanyProfile) # this will error I think
    company_services = CompanyServices.objects.all()

    context = {
        'services': company_services,
        'company_profile': company_profile,
    }

    return render(request, 'webpages/index.html', context=context)
```

base.html

```
<div class="container d-flex">
    <div class="contact-info mr-auto">
        <i class="icofont-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:contact@example.com">***{{ company_profile.company_email }}***</a>
        <i class="icofont-phone"></i> ***{{ company_profile.company_name }}***
</div>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<div>
REST OF THE PAGE CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

**NOTE**: just calling `get_object_or_404()` will cause an error, because you're not giving it the parameter to look up by, so you'll need to pass it something like `pk` or `id` to perform the look up. Something like `get_object_or_404(CompanyProfile, pk=<some_pk_value>)`

Also, if the `base.html` is used across the whole site, you'll need to have the `company_profile` in the context for each view that extends that template. Check out context processors as a nice way of adding this into the context data for every view.

Comment: Thanks @RHSmith159, this was what I did initially, it worked on my local machine until I deployed to Heroku before it started trowing errors saying the models was not found.

I called the model in all views which rendered different pages but extends base.html

Comment: As I am a beginner, the error was too much and I got confused. That is why I am starting it afresh, I will do it again and update you if it throws any error.

Comment: Hello  @RHSmith. Please see below Errors.

ProgrammingError at /

relation "webpages_companyprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "webpages_companyprofile"."company_twitter" FROM "webpages_...

this is the URL: https://psmhome.herokuapp.com/

this is the Github repo: https://github.com/omolojakazeem/prosoft_web.git

Comment: @KazeemOluwatobiOmoloja  thanks for that, Have you run manage.py makemigrations and manage.py migrate? That error is because there are relations that do not exist in the database I think

Comment: Yeas, I did that before deployment. I just confirmed now and it shows no migration.

Comment: Did you run it on the server too?

Comment: I left Debugging True, U will see that it's pointing to base.html. Can u also take a look at the Git repo?

Comment: I added the release command in the wsgi file to migrate. Now error as cleared but the webpage is blank

Comment: the errors have cleared, but noting is displaying on the page now aside the page title.